# PayPal Express Checkout apply shipping costs after SetExpressCheckout call

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I'm currenty implementing In-Context PayPal Express Checkout on our own e-commerce site. The flow I follow is this:

1. Cart
2. Redirect to PayPal
3. Login, select shipping address and confirm
4. Get back to e-commerce
5. Get buyer's shipping address
6. Choose a shipping option
7. Show order summary, confirm order and *DoExpressCheckoutPayment*

My questions are:

I include the shipping costs in *DoExpressCheckoutPayment* call, but not in *SetExpressCheckout* and payments are completed(on sandbox at least). Are there any limitations/problems to that?

It bugs me that the In-Context popup says *Pay Now* before the user has chosen shipping option on our site and seen the complete summary of his/her order. Is there any way to change that text? Maybe something I need to pass with the call?

Maybe there's something I'm missing on how Express Checkout works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly how EC is designed to be used. PayPal expects that final amount may not be the same as the initial amount. If it's within 20% things will essentially always work; if the cart value changes a lot (e.g. you upsell someone to add more goods into the purchase) then it's possible (rare, but possible) that the initial authorization won't stretch to the new value; in that case you can usually send them back to PayPal to re-authorize the higher amount.

As for the action button, I'm surprised that it says Pay Now; it normally says something like "Continue" unless you have turned on the feature to have the payment made immediately at PayPal rather than using DoEC. But the text of this button is not directly under your control; maybe PayPal has changed it because they did some user testing and found higher conversion rates? Not sure.

Comment: Thanks, I just did a successful payment on sandbox where I initially sent $0.69 and in DoExpressCheckoutPayment sent $300+ shipping costs. Are these 20% some kind of a limitation on live paypal?

Comment: There is no 20% limit. There is a 20% "expected overage." Imagine that a user has $50 in their PayPal balance and a credit card in their account.... but the card is expired. If you SetEC for $.69, PayPal won't care about the credit card because it isn't expected to be needed. If you SetEC for $250, PayPal would check the card and prompt the user to update it before they returned the user to you as ready-to-pay. So getting $300 from this user would fail with a $.69 SetEC but succeed with a $250 SetEC. A different user with a good card might work either way. Make sense? This is just an example.